# how to find the latest revisions updated datetime and oldest revisions datetime in postgres with procedure_fk filter in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2

These are my tables i should find the latest  revisions updated datetime and oldest revisions datetime in postgres with procedure_fk filter

can any one help me 
thanks in advance

```
CREATE TABLE "study" (
"pk" SERIAL    PRIMARY KEY,
"procedure_runtime_fk" BIGINT,
"patient_fk" BIGINT,
"modality_infra_fk" BIGINT,
"priority_fk" BIGINT,
"status_fk" BIGINT,
"pacs_server_fk" BIGINT,
"study_iuid" VARCHAR(1024)   UNIQUE,
"study_datetime" TIMESTAMP,
"accession_no" VARCHAR(128),
"study_desc" TEXT,
"mods_in_study" TEXT,
"num_series" BIGINT,
"num_instances" BIGINT,
"availibility" VARCHAR(32),
"ref_physician" VARCHAR(255),
"create_datetime" TIMESTAMP,
"childs" TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE "procedure_runtime_information" (
"pk" SERIAL    PRIMARY KEY,
"patient_fk" BIGINT,
"patient_visit_fk" BIGINT,
"procedure_fk" BIGINT,
"procedure_performed_datetime" TIMESTAMP,
"author_fk" BIGINT,
"creation_datetime" TIMESTAMP,
"procedure_actual_duration" BIGINT,
"procedure_indications" TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
"pre_procedure_info" TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
"procedure_description" TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
"procedure_exposure" TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
"procedure_skindose" TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
"ref_phys_fk" BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
"object_type" BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
"priority_fk" BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
"procedure_id" VARCHAR(256) DEFAULT NULL,
"patient_arrival_datetime" TIMESTAMP,
"procedure_start_datetime" TIMESTAMP

);


CREATE TABLE "report_history" (
"pk" SERIAL    PRIMARY KEY,
"revision" BIGINT,
"report_fk" BIGINT,
"old_status_fk" BIGINT,
"updatedby_fk" BIGINT,
"updated_datetime" TIMESTAMP,
"file_path" TEXT,
"synopsis" TEXT
);



CREATE TABLE "report" (
"pk" SERIAL    PRIMARY KEY,
"report_uuid" VARCHAR(32)   UNIQUE,
"study_fk" BIGINT,
"status_fk" BIGINT,
"priority_fk" BIGINT,
"report_relative_path" VARCHAR(256),
"report_type_fk" BIGINT,
"createdby_fk" BIGINT,
"created_datetime" TIMESTAMP
);
```

Comment: i need to find the latest revisions updated_datetime and the oldest revisions updated datetime for a given procedure_fk in procedure_runtime_information table

Comment: can any one help with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't completely understand what you are trying to do here, but your relationships are not complete clear to me.  But, you should be able to filter based off the min and max.  For example, if you had the following:

```
Create table foo(
id serial, 
foo_detail text);

create table foo_history
(id serial, 
foo_id int references foo(id),
some_new_info text,
modified timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
);

create index idx_foo_history_modified on foo_history using btree (modified)

(select * from foo f
inner join foo_history fh on (fh.foo_id = f.id)
where f.id = 3
order by fh.modified asc
limit 1)
UNION ALL
(select * from foo f
inner join foo_history fh on (fh.foo_id = f.id)
where f.id = 3
order by fh.modified desc
limit 1);
```

You could also do it with a subquery, like the following, but I believe the union will be more efficient.

```
select * from foo f
inner join foo_history fh on (fh.foo_id = f.id)
where f.id = 3
and fh.id = (select max(id) from foo_history where foo_id = 3)
or fh.id = (select min(id) from foo_history where foo_id = 3);
```

Hope this helps.  By the way, you should include the version of Postgresql you are using. I use 9.1 and this answer was developed from my experience with it.

Comment: select * from (
select max(h.updated_datetime) as max, min(h.updated_datetime) as min from report r, report_history h, procedure_runtime_information PRI, study S
where 
h.report_fk=r.pk and
r.study_fk=S.pk and
PRI.pk=S.procedure_runtime_fk and
extract(epoch from (max(h.updated_datetime) - min(h.updated_datetime) ) <=900 and
h.pk IN (
select pk from 
(select * from report_history where report_fk=r.pk) as result
)  and r.status_fk =21 group by r.pk)as result1;